# function call with '$' as parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a script which contains the following piece of code:

```
(function ($) {
  // ...
})($);
```

Can anyone explain how to read it?

Comment: `$` is just a variable, in your case its probably jQuery main object.

Comment: Just as a note: You'd probably be better with using `(function($){...})(jQuery);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Create an anonymous function
2. Let it take one argument which will be called `$`
3. Call the function immediately
4. Pass it one argument which is whatever the value of `$` is in the outer scope.

If the `$` in the outer scope changes (by having a new value assign to it) then the value for `$` in the inner scope will be protected from the change (since it is a different variable).

This also provides a clean scope for all other variables declared inside the function (if they use `var` as they should).

Answer (score 1):

'$' is a legal variable in JavaScript. It could have just as easily been someCrazyLongVariableName

Answer (score 0):

It kind of defeats the purpose of encapsulating the `$` sign into an anonymous function.
It's a self executing anonymous function that takes `$` as argument.
In most of the cases, you use this markup to avoid js libraries collisions : say that you want to use jQuery and prototype in your project. Very nice, but they both use the '$' sign... how to overcome this?

```
// jquery code here
(function($){
    alert($ === jQuery);// the $ is a shortcut to jQuery
})(jQuery);

 // non-jquery code here - ex: prototype
 alert($ === jQuery);// the $ is NOT a shortcut to jQuery ANYMORE
```

Comment: Depends, maybe `$` is changed in the outer scope afterwards... thought *if* it is jQuery, then one should pass `jQuery` instead imo.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not thinking about the $ in particular, the extract is creating a javascript function and calling it in a single statement.

I'm not 100% sure, but i guess that the 2 $ variables would be a different scope.

I found this page useful, if a little verbose: -

http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/JavaScript_DollarSign

In summary, it's no different to calling the variable a, but should be avoided.